# Copy python string characters to array.array (to be accessed later from C++)?

Tags: python, c++, arrays, string, data-conversion

How can one copy python string characters to `array.array`?

```py
from array import array
b  = array('b', [0]*30)
s = 'abc'
# What should one do here to copy integer representation of 's' characters to 'b' ?
```

The integer representation of `s` characters should make sense to C++: i.e. if I convert the integers in `b` to C++ `char` string, I should get back "abc".

The best idea I have is below (but it would be good avoid explicit python loops):

```py
for n,c in enumerate(s): b[n] = ord(c)
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: can you please specify how do you access it from c++ later? is it saved to a file? which format?

Comment: The best idea I have is: `for n,c in enumerate(s): b[n] = ord(c)`.

Comment: @prophet-five If it helps, here is what I will do: https://root.cern.ch/root/htmldoc/guides/users-guide/ROOTUsersGuide.html#writing-a-tree

Comment: have you tried making a list of the characters of the string? something like this: 
`sArr = array('sArr',([*s]+['\0']))`

Comment: The characters have to be copied to an existing array (I can not create a new array): C++ code will access the specified region in memory.

Comment: so do you have that array allocated already? you have to have some space allocated with enough to host the number of characters of s.

Comment: @prophet-five correct, as one can see from my example, I have allocated space in the array for strings up to 30 characters long

Comment: oh I thought it is for a separate purpose. can you change the order, i.e create the list of chars and then using it in the creation of the array?

Comment: No, there will be hundreds of millions of such strings which need to be copied into the single array one by one.

Comment: code format not so good here, i put it in an answer below

Answer (score 0):

try clearing it and filling it again:

```
for i in range(29,-1,-1):
    b.pop(i)
len0s = 29 - len(s)
s_lst = [*s]+['\0']+[0]*len0s
b.fromlist(s_lst)
```

should work if s is under 30 characters

array methods from https://pythongeeks.org/python-array-module/

Comment: There is no need to clear the array. My existing solution (`for n,c in enumerate(s): b[n] = ord(c)`) will just overwrite the content of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you have the 30-byte array populated ahead of time:

```
b = array('b', bytes(s, 'utf-8') + b[len(s):])
```

Or if you want to make it from scratch:

```
b = array('b', bytes(s, 'utf-8') + b'\0' * (30 - len(s)))
```

Or using the `struct` module:

```
struct.pack_into('30s', b, 0, bytes(s, 'utf-8'))
```